# Javascript - push String to Array returns Integer

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I add some strings in an array.

```
console.log(arr1); // ['product_1']
let arr2 = arr1.push(name);
console.log(arr2); // 2
```

Why I receive number 2 in the second log when name is a String too?

- I tried also let arr2 = arr1.slice().push(name); without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr.push()` modifies the `arr` itself and returns the length of the resulting array, to do what you want to do, you can do one of the two following methods

```js
const name = "test";
arr1 = ['product_1'];

// Method 1
let arr2 = [...arr1, name]
console.log(arr2);

// Method 2
arr1.push(name);
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The number 2 in this case is the length of your array.

[Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)